destination with the same identifier (paracol)
I creates short text which creates for me problem during compilation.
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\renewcommand\theHchapter{E.\arabic{chapter}}%
\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\makeatletter
\newcommand\StartLabelItem[1][theorem]%
{
%\counterwithin{enumi}{#1}%
\expandafter \def \csname%
theenumi\expandafter \endcsname \expandafter {\csname the#1\expandafter%
\endcsname.\expandafter \@arabic \csname c@enumi\endcsname }%
\def\labelenumi{\theenumi:}%
}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter{theorem}
\globalcounter{enumi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{C One}
\section{S One}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{theorem}
\label{theorem one}
abc
\StartLabelItem
\begin{enumerate}
\item
the one
\label{item one}
\item
the two
\label{item two}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\switchcolumn
\begin{theorem}
\label{theorem two}
abc
\StartLabelItem
\begin{enumerate}
\item
the one
\label{item one a}
\item
the two
\label{item two a}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}

When I compile this text, I get error
**  pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{Item.1}) has
been already used, duplicate ignored **
My first impression was that report of error was mistake because all references work properly. But when I looked in aux file I saw following
\newlabel{theorem one}{{1.1.1}{1}{}{theorem.E.1.1.1}{}}
\newlabel{item one}{{1.1.1.1}{1}{}{Item.1}{}}
\newlabel{item two}{{1.1.1.2}{1}{}{Item.2}{}}
\newlabel{theorem two}{{1.1.2}{1}{}{theorem.E.1.1.2}{}}
\newlabel{item one a}{{1.1.2.1}{1}{}{Item.1}{}}
\newlabel{item two a}{{1.1.2.2}{1}{}{Item.2}{}} ** 

In my original code instead of item.1 and item.2 was reference to number of theorem, and it postponed to later code which made harder to find source of problem. So to fix the problem, I need to make sure that last 2 lines has item.3 and item.4
The question is how I can do it
Thank you

well did you try \globalcounter{Item} ?

Yes, it works, Thank you. I did not think that item is counter.

This problem is solved now by using the newest paracol release, which changed \theHcountername to contain a columncolumn number prefix for all local counters (relevant for local section numbering etc.). Hence, without any change on your side the aux file now contains
\newlabel{theorem one}{{1.1.1}{1}{}{theorem.column0.column0.E.1.1.1}{}}
\newlabel{item one}{{1.1.1.1}{1}{}{Item.column0.1}{}}
\newlabel{item two}{{1.1.1.2}{1}{}{Item.column0.2}{}}
\newlabel{theorem two}{{1.1.2}{1}{}{theorem.column1.column1.E.1.1.2}{}}
\newlabel{item one a}{{1.1.2.1}{1}{}{Item.column1.1}{}}
\newlabel{item two a}{{1.1.2.2}{1}{}{Item.column1.2}{}}

yielding no troubles any more.
[Yes, it may happen that columnx gets added multiple times (e.g. \theHtheorem calls \theHchapter and both get a columnx prefix). But that seems fine to me.]
